# merging Angular .htaccess with Prerender.io .htaccess

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, prerender

I have been using the following .htaccess file in Angular apps, which avoids the 'page not found...' when user does a manual refresh on a path other than root path, or enters a url path that does not exist.

```
# For instructions and new versions of this Gist go to:
# https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/bcf277cb56d2420cc53ec630a04a3566
# Version 1.4.0

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
    # If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    # --

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>

#------------ BROWSER CACHING (optional)
# Disable browser caching in production. You can add/remove file extension as you wish.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|json|css)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
#------------
```

I am using [prerender.io](https://prerender.io) for social media crawlers etc. They supply following .htaccess to enable redirect to the cached site on a user-agent basis. It is working and I have tested the correct meta tags are read in the [facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

```
# Change YOUR_TOKEN to your prerender token
# Change https://service.prerender.io/ (at the end of the last RewriteRule)
# to http://localhost:3000/ when testing with a local prerender server

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "YOUR_TOKEN"
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Version "prerender-apache@2.0.0"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff|\.svg))

        RewriteRule ^(index\.html|index\.php)?(.*) https://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,END]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

My problem arises from trying to combine rules in both .htaccess files to achieve the effects of both simultaneously. When I include:

```
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

the crawlers no longer get redirected to preloader.io service. If I don't include the rules above the angular app is broken in the way that it cant manually reload on a url path other than root path.

Here is a non-working .htaccess I have tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
    # If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    # --

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]

</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "MY_TOKEN_WAS_HERE"
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Version "prerender-apache@2.0.0"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff|\.svg))

        RewriteRule ^(index\.html|index\.php)?(.*) https://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,END]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I have put the prerender.io proxy rewrite rule to the top, and included the [L] flag in the rule, which stops apache processing further rewrite rules below in the .htaccess file... Seems to work. Maybe this will help someone so I'm posting it here

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff|\.svg))

        RewriteRule ^(index\.html|index\.php)?(.*) https://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,END,L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
    # If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    # --

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]

</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "XVkAwr4MuWz9K5q9Lp4X"
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Version "prerender-apache@2.0.0"
</IfModule>
```